# C Programming - Sum of 2D arrays

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

I am trying to get the values of diagonal values from a 2D array. For example..

```
10 20 30
10 20 30
10 20 30
```

From my codes, I will be adding/summing the numbers from index[0][0] with index[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psupa.png) and index[2][2] USING POINTERS which will compute to 60. However, when I build and run, it returns computation of the memory address instead. Anyone can explain the problem here? (I'm new to C programming and pointers)

```
void diagonals2D(int array[][SIZE], int rowSize, int colSize, int *sum)
{
    int count;
    *sum=0;

    for(count=0;count<SIZE;count++)
    {
        (*sum)+=*(array+count+count);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: `*(array+count+count)` --> `array[count][count]`

Comment: @Han (*sum)+=*( *( array+count )+count);

Comment: I've edited my answer and it seems to work, check it out

Comment: How is the 'USING POINTERS' constraint useful to future users/visitors?  The trivial [xy][xy] indexing is much clearer.

Comment: oh thank you! it's working :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter is adjusted to

```
int ( *array )[SIZE]
```

that is it is a pointer.

So the expression `array + count` also has the type `int ( * )[SIZE]`. To get the corresponding "row" of the array you have to dereference the pointer

```
*( array + count )
```

In this case you will have an object of the type `int[SIZE]` that in turn in the expression

```
*( array + count ) + count
```

is implicitly convered to the type `int *.`

Now dereferencing the whole expression you will get the target element

```
*( *( array + count ) + count )
```

It is better to declare the function as having the parameter of the variable length array.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void diagonals2D( long long int *sum, size_t n, int a[n][n] )
{
    *sum = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *sum += *( *( a + i ) + i );
    }
}

#define N   3

int main(void) 
{
    int a[][N] =
    {
        { 10, 20, 30 },
        { 10, 20, 30 },
        { 10, 20, 30 }      
    };

    long long int sum;

    diagonals2D( &sum, N, a );

    printf( "sum = %lld\n", sum );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sum = 60
```

Comment: @Han See my demonstrative program and compare its output with your output to find the difference. Maybe in a printf call you are using expression &sum instead of sum.

Answer (score 0):

That `array+count+count` is not equivalent to `array[count][count]`, that is what you need to achieve. 
The best way you could achieve it is the cleaner `array[count][count]` but if you want to stick with pointers arithmetic from a learning point of view (again, this is bad for readability and debugging) you should access the element this way:

```
(*sum)+=*(*(array+count)+count);
```

This way you add `count` to the base pointer `array`, memory location of the base address of the `count`th row. It's a pointer to a pointer.

Dereferencing it will give you the base address of the row.

Adding `count` to the base pointer for the row will give you the address of the `count`th element of the row, and dereferencing it will give you the value of the element.

See the code [here](http://rextester.com/live/RWD10522)

Comment: In the OP's snippet's context "*`*(array + count * SIZE + count)`*" does not evaluate to an `int`!

Comment: what do you mean? The memory location that's dereferenced looks ok to me. Let me try, wait

Comment: I want to say that `int array[][SIZE]` and `int array[SIZE]` are *not* the same.

Comment: Doing `int i = *(array + count * SIZE + count);` would not do what you expect.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added a working code example. I hope it's ok now

Comment: I'm sorry if I wrote wrong stuff before, hope I didn't confuse you!

Answer (score 0):

As the given problem,you should use the following code.

```
for(count = 0; count < size; count++)
   sum=*( *( array + count ) + count);
```